# Ajax sometimes fails to parse the large JSON response

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am calling a PHP service with below ajax code :

```
    jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?option=com_sheet&task=getReportsData',
    timeout: 300000,
    dataType: "json",
    type: "GET",
    data: {        
        'project': projectsStr,
        'startweek': startweek,
        'endweek': endweek        
    }
}).done(function(response) {    
    if (response.success && response.data) {
        var projectData = response.data;
        if (projectData.projectReportData.length > 0) {
            loadDataTable(response.data);
        } else {
            jQuery('#projectReportData').html("<br/><h2>No Matching Results</h2>");
        }
    }
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    jQuery(".overlay")[0].style.display = '';
    if (textStatus === 'timeout') {
        alert('Failed from timeout');        
    }
    alert(textStatus);
});
```

The php code that provides the response prints the response with :

```
$data = (object)array_merge(['projectReportData' => $projectReportData]);
header("Content-Type: application/json");
$post_data = json_encode($data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
ob_start('ob_gzhandler');   
echo new JResponseJson($data);
ob_end_flush();
jexit();
```

This ajax works fine sometimes and is able to parse the JSON. But most of the times gives "parsererror". 
Below code fetch the data from the DB :

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
  $query = "CALL getReportData('" . $startweek . "','" . $endweek . "')";
  $db->setQuery($query);     
  $res = $db->query($query);
  $returnArr = [];
  $i = 0;
  while( $r = $res->fetch_assoc()){
    $projectReportData[$i] = $r;
    $i++;

  }
```

when i change `dataType` to `text` the pointer reaches the `.done()` but `console.log(response)` returns a blank.

Comment: can you print the code you use to fetch the data given from jquery

Comment: You should be able to extract the json (string) when it gives that error and then put it into a json parser (eg https://jsonlint.com/) to see where the problem is.

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI, its already mentioned in the question. do you need anything else?

Comment: @freedomn-m, let me give it a try, but the JSON is pretty big, when I try to paste it in the JSON formatters, the browser hangs.

Comment: the ob_gzhandler function , you said that php code is for the response

Comment: Browsers really aren't designed for OLAP - you should probably rethink your design - possibly generate/summarise the report server-side

Comment: @SalilLambay you use the `JSON.parse(response)` after `.done(function(response){ var res=JSON.parse(response); })` .

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI, added the php code to fetch the data

Comment: @SubhashPatel, but it is going to the .fail( block so no use of using JSON.parse response in done.

Comment: Can you show us the error result? Where do you parse json data to js object?

Comment: @SubhashPatel for that to be helpful, `dataType: "json"` would need to be removed from the AJAX settings first, because that is telling jQuery to automatically parse the response as JSON, _before_ it reaches the `.done()` callback. You needed to mention that in your advice.

Comment: @hurricane, but code takes me to the fail block and hence the pointer doesnt reach te place where i am trying to consume the JSON data

Comment: @SubhashPatel, when i change the dataType to text, the response is blank

Comment: @SalilLambay Open your console and check what is the issue or catch your error in fail method.